# javascript code to restrict user clicking/submitting when reaches the limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am working on google charts in angular application.Scenario is when user click on the legend of the chart, the corresponding data is hidden on the chart. I want to limit the hiding of the data so that the chart is not blank without data. Atleast one series of data should be visible. User can able to select the legend and hide only 3 legends data and when user select the 4th legend i need to show an alert saying "CANNOT HIDE ENTIRE DATA OF THE CHART" and stop hiding the data of that legend.

Working sample https://plnkr.co/edit/OBsZFO8LerlKcWAu65sZ?p=preview

In the example above, user can able to hide the data of all the legends and the chart area will be blank. I need to restrict so that always one legend data is shown on the graph. Any inputs would be helpful.

js code:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['googlechart'])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
    var chart1 = {};
    chart1.type = "LineChart";
    chart1.displayed = false;
    chart1.data = {
      "cols": [{
        id: "month",
        label: "Month",
        type: "string"
      }, {
        id: "laptop-id",
        label: "Laptop",
        type: "number"
      }, {
        id: "desktop-id",
        label: "Desktop",
        type: "number"
      }, {
        id: "server-id",
        label: "Server",
        type: "number"
      }, {
        id: "cost-id",
        label: "Shipping",
        type: "number"
      }],
      "rows": [{
        c: [{
          v: "January"
        }, {
          v: 19,
          f: "42 items"
        }, {
          v: 12,
          f: "Ony 12 items"
        }, {
          v: 7,
          f: "7 servers"
        }, {
          v: 4
        }]
      }, {
        c: [{
          v: "February"
        }, {
          v: 13
        }, {
          v: 1,
          f: "1 unit (Out of stock this month)"
        }, {
          v: 12
        }, {
          v: 2
        }]
      }, {
        c: [{
            v: "March"
          }, {
            v: 24
          }, {
            v: 5
          }, {
            v: 11
          }, {
            v: 6
          }

        ]
      }]
    };
    chart1.options = {
      "title": "Sales per month",
      "colors": ['#0000FF', '#009900', '#CC0000', '#DD9900'],
      "defaultColors": ['#0000FF', '#009900', '#CC0000', '#DD9900'],
      "isStacked": "true",
      "fill": 20,
      "displayExactValues": true,
      "vAxis": {
        "title": "Sales unit",
        "gridlines": {
          "count": 10
        }
      },
      "hAxis": {
        "title": "Date"
      }
    };
    chart1.view = {
      columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    };
    $scope.myChart = chart1;

    var hidden = [];

    $scope.seriesSelected = function(selectedItem) {

      var col = selectedItem.column;
      hidden.push(col);

    /*  if (hidden.length === ($scope.myChart.view.columns.length  -1 )) {
        window.alert("you can't remove all cols!");

      }*/

      console.log(selectedItem);

      //If there's no row value, user clicked the legend.
      if (selectedItem.row === null) {
        //If true, the chart series is currently displayed normally.  Hide it.
        console.log($scope.myChart.view.columns[col]);

        $scope.reset = function() {
          for (var i = 0; i < hidden.length; i++) {
            var hiddenCol = hidden[i];
            $scope.myChart.view.columns[hiddenCol] = hiddenCol;
            $scope.myChart.options.colors[hiddenCol - 1] = $scope.myChart.options.defaultColors[hiddenCol - 1];

          }

          //$scope.myChart.view.columns[col] = col;
          //console.log($scope.myChart.view.columns[col]);

        }

        if ($scope.myChart.view.columns[col] == col) {
          //Replace the integer value with this object initializer.
          $scope.myChart.view.columns[col] = {
            //Take the label value and type from the existing column.
            label: $scope.myChart.data.cols[col].label,
            type: $scope.myChart.data.cols[col].type,
            //makes the new column a calculated column based on a function that returns null, 
            //effectively hiding the series.
            calc: function() {
              return null;
            }
          };
          //Change the series color to grey to indicate that it is hidden.
          //Uses color[col-1] instead of colors[col] because the domain column (in my case the date values)
          //does not need a color value.
          $scope.myChart.options.colors[col - 1] = '#CCCCCC';
        }
        //series is currently hidden, bring it back.
        else {
          console.log("Ran this.");
          //Simply reassigning the integer column index value removes the calculated column.
          $scope.myChart.view.columns[col] = col;
          console.log($scope.myChart.view.columns[col]);
          //I had the original colors already backed up in another array.  If you want to do this in a more
          //dynamic way (say if the user could change colors for example), then you'd need to have them backed
          //up when you switch to grey.
          $scope.myChart.options.colors[col - 1] = $scope.myChart.options.defaultColors[col - 1];
        }
      }
      $scope.serverId = chart1.data.rows[selectedItem.row].c[3].v;
      alert("serverid : " + $scope.serverId);


    };
  });
```

html code:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <div google-chart chart="myChart" on-select="seriesSelected(selectedItem)"></div></div>
```

Need to restrict the user by selecting the legend to hide the data if only one legend data is shown on the webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you just need to keep control of the hidden series.  Add or remove from the array of hidden series.

Please check [this working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/1W16tpSGybEctyXYgYT1?p=preview)

The important part:

```
var colIndex = hidden.indexOf(col);
if (hidden.length === ($scope.myChart.view.columns.length-2) && colIndex == -1) {
        window.alert("you can't remove all cols!");
}
else{            
   if(colIndex == -1){
      hidden.push(col);
   }
   else{
      hidden.splice(colIndex, 1);
   }
```

and you have to reset the hidden array when the chart is cleared:

```
$scope.reset = function() {
   for (var i = 0; i < hidden.length; i++) {
      var hiddenCol = hidden[i];
      $scope.myChart.view.columns[hiddenCol] = hiddenCol;
      $scope.myChart.options.colors[hiddenCol - 1] = $scope.myChart.options.defaultColors[hiddenCol - 1];
   }
   hidden = [];      
};
```

Comment: This example https://plnkr.co/edit/1W16tpSGybEctyXYgYT1?p=preview you mentioned above is working only for first time, when user click on Clear button, and again try to select the legend it is allowing to select/hide all the legends to hide the data.Any inputs ? @ednincer

Comment: You just need to clear the hidden array when you reset the chart.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/5S7C86ofBtQsZVYXONeF?p=preview , plesae find the updated plunker, it is failing in multiple scenarios after the hidden array is cleared also. When alert is displayed "you can't remove all cols!" when i click on tooltip of line chart the same message is being displayed.

Comment: Check the answer's updated plunker. Both problems are solved.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work for me...

```
var hidden = [];

$scope.seriesSelected = function(selectedItem) {

  if (hidden.length === 3) {
    window.alert("you can't remove all cols!");
    return 0;
  }

  var col = selectedItem.column;
  hidden.push(col);



  console.log(selectedItem);

  //If there's no row value, user clicked the legend.
  if (selectedItem.row === null) {
    //If true, the chart series is currently displayed normally.  Hide it.
    console.log($scope.myChart.view.columns[col]);

    $scope.reset = function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < hidden.length; i++) {
        var hiddenCol = hidden[i];
        $scope.myChart.view.columns[hiddenCol] = hiddenCol;
        $scope.myChart.options.colors[hiddenCol - 1] = $scope.myChart.options.defaultColors[hiddenCol - 1];

      }
      hidden = [];

      //$scope.myChart.view.columns[col] = col;
      //console.log($scope.myChart.view.columns[col]);

    }
```

Comment: Thankyou, appreciate your response. One thing i noticed was after the alert message, it is not allowing to further select the legend which were already hidden to make the corresponding legend data visible.And other major issue is when user select and deselect the legend multiple times, it is counting and showing alert after 4times the user has selected/deselected the legend. This should not happen.  Even i was facing the same issues here before i posted the question..

Comment: Well, you didn't specify any of that in your question.  What do you think I am, a mind-reader?  :)